# What does "Find pattern" mean in data science?

Tags: data-mining, dataset, categorical-data

I am doing certification and i have a project to complete. In project, they have said "Find Patterns". What does it mean? what steps should i carry out?

Answer (score 2):

*First*, I'm going to directly quote the two inner questions you put in this question:

> "Find Patterns", What does it mean?:

Find patterns is the term given to the process of analyzing data(Data Analysis) or dataset for insights in it that is to say; the classification of input into per-determined categories,recognize particular categories of input by their characteristics.

So when they ask you to **find patterns**,they assume that you don't necessarily know what is in that data(it can be structured,semi-structured and unstructured) so you can't even make decisions upon that data.therefore you have to find patterns in it. You have to look for them, which can often involve a lot of hunch-following and guess-work combined with a bit of solid testing.you tend to know the patterns already and you search for them based on their features or attributes etc.

> what steps should i carry out?

1. Ask Question
2. Do some background research
3. Construct hypothesis
4. Test with an experiment
5. Analyze results and draw effective conclusions.

**Concerning Hypothesis**

```
If the hypothesis is true,then proceed and report results
or Else,if it's false or partially true report results.
```

Hope this can give you a glimpse.

Comment: Does that involve finding the mean,median,std etc?

Comment: I am just a beginner, exploring data science now. I have  a data set in excel sheet. Project snippet is as follows :- "Perform a service request data analysis  You will focus on the data wrangling techniques to understand the pattern in the data and also visualize the major complaint types." And it says "Find Pattern"

Comment: what does "Find pattern"mean in this perspective?

Comment: Parts of this answer appear to be copied word-for-word from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14331093/781723, without attribution.  [Plagiarism](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).